# Skip punctuation char when shifting words in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, shift

Strings are to be input by user. Then the program will shift the strings in the word by input. The problem is, whenever it tried to shift over z, there will be punctuation char. How to overcome this problem?

```
printf("Enter text : ");
scanf("%s",&plaint);

printf("Enter shift amount : ");
scanf("%d",&shif);

for(int j=0; plaint[j] != '\0'; j++)
{
    plaint[j]=plaint[j]+shif;
}
```

Comment: what would you expect to happen when you try to shift 'z' by one?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [ASCII code chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) after `Z` and `z` there are punctuations. To make a jump from z to a use modulo operation (`%`). For example:

```
char plaint[101];
int shif;

printf("Enter text : "); 
scanf("%100s",plaint);

printf("Enter shift amount : ");
scanf("%d",&shif);

for(int j=0; plaint[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    if( plaint[j] >= 'A' && plaint[j] <= 'Z' )
        plaint[j] = (plaint[j] -'A' + shif) % 26 + 'A';

    if( plaint[j] >= 'a' && plaint[j] <= 'z' )
        plaint[j] = (plaint[j] -'a' + shif) % 26 + 'a';

    if( plaint[j] >= '0' && plaint[j] <= '9' )
        plaint[j] = (plaint[j] -'0' + shif) % 10 + '0';
}
```

This will shift only letters and digits, and wrap around z and 9. First I move letters to be in numerical value range 0-25, and digits to be in 0-9, then add shift and use modulo, and then move back to its original place in ASCII chart by adding `'a'` (97), `'A'` (65), or `'0'` (48).

Puncutations and other characters will not be changed.

Comment: thank you, you really help a lot

Comment: That's pretty slick, just a tweak to `scanf("%100s",&plaint);` (no `&`, `plaint` is a pointer...)